# Having trouble with my Fahrenheit to Celcius/Kelvin converter

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

```
# Fahrenheit to Celcius    
def f2c():
    userInput = tempEntry.get().lower()
    thisEquation = "Fahrenheit to Celcius"
    if userInput == "":
        textWid.insert(END,"-- " + thisEquation + " --")
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
        textWid.insert(END,temp_equations[thisEquation])
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
    elif userInput.isdigit():
        textWid.insert(END,"Fahrenheit = ")
        textWid.insert(END,str(((float(userInput) - 32) * (5/9))))
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
    else:
        textWid.insert(END,"Invalid entry for"+" "+thisEquation)
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")

# Fahrenheit to Kelvin
def f2k():
    userInput = tempEntry.get().lower()
    thisEquation = "Fahrenheit to Kelvin"
    if userInput == "":
        textWid.insert(END,"-- " + thisEquation + " --")
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
        textWid.insert(END,temp_equations[thisEquation])
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
    elif userInput.isdigit():
        textWid.insert(END,"Fahrenheit = ")
        textWid.insert(END,str(((5/9)*(float(userInput) - 32) + 273.15)))
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
    else:
        textWid.insert(END,"Invalid entry for"+" "+thisEquation)
        textWid.insert(END,"\n")
```

userInput is a Tkinter Entry box defined globally. 
I have a strong suspicion that my problem stems from the two equations, but I've tried re-working them many times.

My Fahrenheit to Celcius converter always returns 0.0
The Fahrenheit to Kelvin converter is about 20 off every time.

Completely stumped here guys, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`5 / 9` is your problem:

```
>>> 5 / 9
    0
```

In Python 2, dividing an integer by an integer yields an integer. You want to make at least one of the numbers a float:

```
>>> 5.0 / 9
    0.5555555555555556
>>> 5.0 / 9.0
    0.5555555555555556
```

Comment: Or both the numbers!  I would put `5.0 / 9.0` just to make it perfectly clear to humans as well as Python.

Comment: +1. You can also solve this by just removing the parentheses: `(float(userInput) - 32) * 5 / 9` multiplies a `float` by an `int`, returning a `float`, then divides by an `int`, returning a `float` again.

Comment: @steveha: Definitely! I often do `5./9` when I'm typing at the interactive console, but try to always do `5.0/9.0` in real code, because it's very easy to miss a single `.` when debugging…

Comment: @blender Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate it. Was pulling my hair out trying to debug this one.